# Upgrade to Piranha 10.1 now all saves/posts in the Manager result in 400 error

Tags: .net, piranha-cms

I recently upgraded a .NET 5 MVC project that is working with Piranha 9.x to .NET 6 and upgraded Piranha to 10.1. Everything works except nothing will save from the Piranha manager. All HTTP POST transactions return a 400 error. I am suspicious of an anti-forgery issue but I can't find any documentation about needing to configure anti-forgery settings except for the anti-forgery cookie name and header.

Has anyone experienced this after upgrading to Piranha 10.x? These are the errors I am seeing in the Piranha manager when trying to save anywhere in the manager:

[image: 400 Error]

[image: Error message in the manager]

Answer (score 3):

I found an issue in GitHub where someone reported this same thing and @tidyui added a comment:

> After successful login you need to redirect to “manager/login/auth” for the anti forgery to be set up correctly.

So I just changed my hyperlink in my MVC project from "/manager" to "manager/login/auth" and now it's working.

Hope this helps anyone else who runs into this after updating Piranha to 10.x